# Why does F. Wagner consider "NOT (AI_LARGER_THAN_8.1)" to be ambiguous?

Tags: design, finite-state-machine

In his article on Virtual Environments (a part of his VFSM specification method) Ferdinand Wagner describes some new ways of thinking about Boolean Algebra as a software design tool.  On [page 4 of this PDF article](http://www.stateworks.com/active/download/TN1-Virtual-Environment.pdf), when describing operators in his system he says this:

> Control statements need Boolean
>   values. Hence, the names must be used
>   to produce Boolean results. To achieve
>   this we want to combine them together
>   using Boolean operators. There is
>   nothing wrong with usage of AND and OR
>   operators with their Boolean meaning.
>   For instance, we may write:
>
> DI_ON OR AI_LARGER_THAN_8.1 AND
>   TIMER_OVER
>
> to express the control situation:
>   digital input is on or analog input is
>   larger than 8.1 and timer is over.
>
> We cannot use the NOT operator,
>   because the result of the Boolean
>   negation makes sense only for true
>   Boolean values. The result of, for
>   instance,
>
> NOT (AI_LARGER_THAN_8.1)
>
> would be ambiguous.

If "AI_LARGER_THAN_8.1" is acceptable, why would he consider "NOT (AI_LARGER_THAN_8.1)" to be ambiguous?

Comment: NOT (AI_LARGER_THAN_8.1) has two potential results: one lesser and one equal??! I don't know...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's an error in this paper.  Wagner claims this is boolean algebra, but also includes 'UNKNOWN' as a value along with TRUE and FALSE.  Therefore, this is not actually boolean algebra but a trinary system of his own creation.

Notably, he does not define NOT with respect to this trinary system.  This is a classic gotcha in trinary systems.  Unlike a binary system, NOT TRUE does not necessarily equal FALSE, nor does NOT FALSE necessarily equal TRUE.

Comment: In a trinary system, NOT TRUE yields FileNotFound... :P http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/What_Is_Truth_0x3f_.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I was coming to the same conclusion, but wanted a second opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is in page 203 of book "Modeling Software with Finite State Machines: A Practical Approach". It says:

"if we define only one control value for the DI object
using either the LOW or HIGH value, the missing entry in VI is ambiguous - it may mean the not used or the unknown control value and we cannot use the absence of a control value for formulating conditions (a rule of our positive-logic algebra)."

So NOT operator could be well defined but it is undesirable in VFSM model.

EDIT

In a sense the VI set, mentioned in this paper, is a knowledge base consisting of positive literals. A transition to a new state is performed if VI entails a given condition. The absence of a name from VI does not infer that the corresponding condition is false (the open-world assumption). Thus, a negative literal can never be a logical consequence of a set of positive literals or, more generally, of a definite clause knowledge base. To conclude, condition NOT(AI_LARGER_THAN_8.1) never leads to transition so it is not used at all.